# How to only access column information given criteria in a different column

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to sum up all numbers from a given group in a tab delimited file in order to plot the information in a histogram. I have wrote the code below...

```
tab_csv <- read.csv("data.csv", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
tab_csv

    label   number
1  group1    120
2  group1    105
3  group1    105
4  group1     84
5  group1     32
6  group2    820
7  group2    922
8  group2    823
9  group2    945
10 group2    849

levels(tab_csv$label)

[1] "group1" "group2"
```

Is there a way to access all the numbers that have the "group1" label to sum the numbers from this group?

Comment: You might find [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) book (and this chapter in particular) very helpful.

Comment: I realise that I posted the wrong link (wrong edition). The newest edition is [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something of the sort of:

```
sum(tab_csv$number[tab_csv$label == "group1"])
```

Steps:

1. Select only the rows that contain "group1" : `log_vector = tab_csv$label == "group1"`
2. Use that logical vector to select the numbers you want to sum: `x =  tab_csv$number[log_vector]`
3. Sum those numbers `sum(x)`

Comment: Thanks @HartRadev! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're welcome @Jordan. If that answered your question, remember to accept my answer (this way it also helps other contributors to see that this question has already been solved).